# Sorting the queue by name doesn't work

Tags: c, sorting, queue

I am supposed to edit the program so it sorts the queue in some order. I have figured out how to do ascending and descending order on the rating (number) but I cannot do the sort by artist (name). Somehow it just doesn't work as I want it to be. "le_item_artist" should make the names entered to be sorted from a to z as it should be but it doesn't. Could you please tell me what's wrong? Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pqueue.h"

struct track
{
    char artist[20];
    char title[20];
    int rating; 
};

void print_item(any i)
{
    printf("(%i,'%s','%s')",
        ((struct track*)i)->rating,
        ((struct track*)i)->artist,
        ((struct track*)i)->title);
}

int le_item_desc(any i, any j)
{
    return ((struct track*)i)->rating <= ((struct track*)j)->rating;
}

int le_item_asc(any i, any j)
{
    return ((struct track*)i)->rating >= ((struct track*)j)->rating;
}

int le_item_artist(any i, any j)
{
    return ((struct track*)i)->artist >= ((struct track*)j)->artist;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char order;

    //Select sorting menu
    printf("Please select one of the following\n");
    printf("(a)scanding\n");
    printf("(d)escending\n");
    printf("Your option: ");

    scanf("%c", &order);

    pqueue *pq = new_bounded_pqueue(5,le_item_desc);
    pqueue *pq2 = new_bounded_pqueue(5,le_item_asc);
    pqueue *pq3 = new_bounded_pqueue(5,le_item_artist);

    struct track *it;
    int i;

    switch(order){
    case 'D':
    case 'd': for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            it = (struct track*)malloc(sizeof(struct track));
            printf("rating artist title? ");scanf(" %i %s %s", &(it->rating), it->artist, it->title);
            pqueue_insert(pq,it);
            pqueue_print(pq,print_item);
            printf("\n\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        pqueue_dequeue(pq);
        pqueue_print(pq,print_item);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 'A':
    case 'a': for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            it = (struct track*)malloc(sizeof(struct track));
            printf("rating artist title? ");scanf(" %i %s %s", &(it->rating), it->artist, it->title);
            pqueue_insert(pq2,it);
            pqueue_print(pq2,print_item);
            printf("\n\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        pqueue_dequeue(pq2);
        pqueue_print(pq2,print_item);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n': for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            it = (struct track*)malloc(sizeof(struct track));
            printf("rating artist title? ");scanf(" %i %s %s", &(it->rating), it->artist, it->title);
            pqueue_insert(pq3,it);
            pqueue_print(pq3,print_item);
            printf("\n\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        pqueue_dequeue(pq3);
        pqueue_print(pq3,print_item);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    break;
    default: printf("Error, wrong character!\n");
    }   

}
```

Comment: Going out on a limb here...  The snippet you provided does not compile, does it.   ***any*** is not a `C` type.  Are you allowed touse `qsort()`?

Comment: `le_item_artist` needs to use `strcmp` to compare the two strings. The current code is just comparing the two pointer values, which won't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`le_item_artist` needs to use `strcmp` to compare the two strings. The current code is just comparing the two pointer values, which won't do what you want.
                    – user3386109